# MySQL randomly generated numbers with letters prefix, and an error using variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I keep researching and researching this, but can't find the answer.  It's probably simple.

I'd like to update my fields with a randomly generated number using a string prefix.  Example: item283940.  Preferably I'd like to start at 1000 and just increment up.  I seem to have most of the query for the random numbers down, however it looks like I'm missing something.

Why is this causing a syntax error?

```
$query = "SET @r := 1000; UPDATE discography SET pagename = (@r := @r + 1) ORDER BY RAND()";

mysql_query($query);
```

Yeilds:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE discography SET pagename = (@r := @r + 1) ORDER BY RAND()' at line 1
```

And once the error is sorted out, I'd like to know how to add the prefix "item" at the beginning of the variable.  Many thanks in advance.

***Edit***

It looks like my server uses an older version of PHP so I can't use mysqli.  In terms of solving my other issues, it's inefficient but this worked for my needs:

```
$setit = "SET @r := 1000";
$changenames = "UPDATE discography SET pagename = (@r := @r + 1) ORDER BY RAND()";
$prepend = "UPDATE discography SET pagename=CONCAT('item',pagename)";
mysql_query($setit);
mysql_query($changenames);
mysql_query($prepend);
```

Comment: php's mysql driver does not allow multiple commands in a single query call as a basic sql injection attack defense mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, obvious mistake!  It works now without an error.  Any ideas on the other part of my q, how to add the "item" prefix in front of the randomly generated number variable?

Comment: `update discography set pagename=concat('item', @r := @r + 1) order by rand()` might work as a single query, but never tried doing a variable update like that inside a function call, so no idea if it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `mysql_query` you can't run multiple queries. The problem arise here.

You have to use `mysqli's` `multi_query` function to run multiple query.

And as a side not stop using `mysql_*` because its deprecated. start using `mysqli` as i mentioned OR `PDO`.

Comment: Oops, rookie mistake!  Thank you for your answer, I changed it and it worked like a charm.  Any ideas on the 2nd part of my question, how to add the "item" prefix in front of the randomly generated number variable?

Comment: I tried this, which didn't work: UPDATE discography SET pagename = 'item'+(@r := @r + 1) ORDER BY RAND();